# Inno Setup - Certificate is not trusted

Tags: ssl, inno-setup

I added certificate to my installer and Avast everytime checking setup.exe for viruses.

Here, how i creating a .PFX file:

```
makecert -sv MyCert.pvk -n "CN=MyCert" MyCert.cer -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2050 -r
```

later

```
pvk2pfx.exe -pvk MyCert.pvk -spc MyCert.cer -pfx MyCert.pfx -po 123
```

Now when i have .PFX file, i'm creating installer with "Compil32", with following parameters:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\signtool.exe" sign /f "C:\MakeCert\MyCert.PFX" /t http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode /p 123 $f
```

Everything is going fine but when i try to install program, Avast pops up window with checking installer.

[image]

[image]

Sorry for my bad English. I hope someone will understand me.

Comment: That seems correct to me. Why did you expect any other results? Self-signed certificate cannot be trusted.

Comment: It's kinda frustrating when Installer is constantly checked by Antivirus Software.

Comment: So what do you actually want? Do you want to prevent your antivirus from checking the installer, while you are developing it? Or do you want your installer be treated as trusted by everyone? (you as well as users of your installer)

Comment: The second one.